# If $x,y$ are element of the finite group $G$ such that $xy=yx$, then is the equation $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$ necessarily true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> If $x,y$ are element of the finite group $G$ such that $xy=yx$, then is the equation $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$ necessarily true?

---

I know that if $x^ny^n=(xy)^n$ then $x$ and $y$ commute, but I am not sure about the converse though.

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: Try proof by induction.

Comment: A simple induction on $n$ for kids is enough to prove it

Comment: Use induction on $n$....

Comment: include your own ideas or work and don't use such a long title, down vote from me sadly

Comment: What you say you know is false: for example, in $\;S_3\;$ , we have that  $\;(12)^6(13)^6=((12)(13))^6\;$ , yet of course $\;(12)(13)=(132)\neq(123)=(13)(12)\;$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Show by induction on $m$ that $xy^m=y^mx$ and $x^my=yx^m$ for any $m\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: That answered my question. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, @Shot :)

Comment: @Shot: if that answers your question, you should probably consider "accept" it by clicking the $\checkmark$ button.

Answer (score 3):

$$(xy)^n=x(yx)^{n-1}y=x(xy)^{n-1}y=\ldots=x^k(xy)^{n-k}y^k=\ldots=x^ny^n$$